# Android Studio - Editor is suddenly working like a Terminal editor

Tags: android-studio, editor

I am using Android Studio to code a flutter app. It was working fine so was able to edit documents like MS Word documents. But suddenly I have to click a key like 'I' to edit documents. It is like editing documents in Terminal. How I can fix it? Please help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

check if you are enabling Vim plugin, if yes disable it. I to edit is a Vim keybinding to enter Insert mode.

https://www.vim.org/docs.php

Comment: Worked! I saved my day!!

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as a solution to help other members in SO!